# Problem compiling a simple CMake Ogre v2.3 project: "Build files cannot be regenerated correctly."

Tags: cmake, ninja, ogre

after I finally built ogre next with the mac build script, I tried creating a simple project, copying the EmptyProject sample, but that does not work. When I compile it using CMake, it gives me this error:

```
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/gcc-12 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/g++-12 -S/Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic -B/Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/build -G Ninja
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- FALSE
[cmake] -- Detected DLL build of Ogre
[cmake] -- Found SDL2
[cmake] -- Detected Atmosphere Component. Linking against it.
[cmake] -- Copying Hlms data files from Ogre repository
[cmake] -- Copying Common data files from Ogre repository
[cmake] -- Copying DLLs and generating Plugins.cfg for Debug
[cmake] -- Copying DLLs and generating Plugins.cfg for Release
[cmake] -- Copying DLLs and generating Plugins.cfg for RelWithDebInfo
[cmake] -- Copying DLLs and generating Plugins.cfg for MinSizeRel
[cmake] -- Generating /Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/bin/Data/resources2.cfg from template
[cmake]         /Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/CMake/Templates/Resources.cfg.in
[cmake] -- Copying OgreSamplesCommon cpp and header files to
[cmake]         /Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/include/OgreCommon
[cmake]         /Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/src/OgreCommon/
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] CMake Error:
[cmake]   Running
[cmake] 
[cmake]    '/usr/local/bin/ninja' '-C' '/Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/build' '-t' 'recompact'
[cmake] 
[cmake]   failed with:
[cmake] 
[cmake]    ninja: error: build.ninja:240: bad $-escape (literal $ must be written as $$)
[cmake] 
[cmake]   

[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
[proc] The command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/gcc-12 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/g++-12 -S/Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic -B/Users/fildom/Developer/CMAKE/obezic/build -G Ninja exited with code: 1
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
#This scripts will add all the cpp and h files under src and include folders, and
#assumes that your Ogre source code is in Dependencies/Ogre and that:
# In Windows you built Ogre into Dependencies/Ogre/build
# In Linux you built Release into Dependencies/Ogre/build/Release
# In Linux you built Debug into Dependencies/Ogre/build/Debug
#
# If your source code is not at "Dependencies/Ogre"; you can use "mklink /D" to create
# a symbolic link to where the source code is located on Windows.
# On Linux, you can use "ln -s"

#set( CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE CMake/iOS.cmake )

cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
project( EmptyProject )

set( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" )

include( CMake/Bootstrap.cmake )
include( CMake/Dependencies/OGRE.cmake )

if( APPLE )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )
endif()

setupOgre( OGRE_SOURCE, OGRE_BINARIES, OGRE_LIBRARIES, FALSE, FALSE )

# Setup our application
set( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" )
if( MSVC )
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP")
    if( NOT PLATFORM_X64 )
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /arch:SSE2")
    endif()
    add_definitions( -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE )
endif()

if( APPLE )
    macro( add_recursive dir retVal )
        file( GLOB_RECURSE ${retVal} ${dir}/*.h ${dir}/*.cpp ${dir}/*.c ${dir}/*.mm ${dir}/*.m )
    endmacro()
else()
    macro( add_recursive dir retVal )
        file( GLOB_RECURSE ${retVal} ${dir}/*.h ${dir}/*.cpp ${dir}/*.c )
    endmacro()
endif()

include_directories( "./include" )
# Ogre doesn't need this include, but we do because of Rapidjson in UnitTesting.cpp
include_directories( "./Dependencies/Ogre/Dependencies/include" )

add_recursive( ./src SOURCES )
add_recursive( ./include HEADERS )

if( APPLE )
    if( APPLE_IOS )
        file( GLOB_RECURSE RESOURCES ./src/*.storyboard )
    endif()
    set( RESOURCES ${RESOURCES}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Data )

    if( APPLE_IOS )
        set_source_files_properties(
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/OgreCommon/System/OSX/OSXUtils.mm
            PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE
        )
    else()
        set_source_files_properties(
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/OgreCommon/System/iOS/AppDelegate.mm
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/OgreCommon/System/iOS/GameViewController.mm
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/OgreCommon/System/iOS/iOSUtils.mm
            PROPERTIES HEADER_FILE_ONLY TRUE
        )
    endif()
endif()

if( APPLE )
    # Treat our *.c & *.cpp files as *.mm + Enable ARC on them
    set_source_files_properties( ${SOURCES} PROPERTIES
        COMPILE_FLAGS
            "-x objective-c++ -fobjc-arc"
    )
endif()

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 MACOSX_BUNDLE ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${RESOURCES} )
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OGRE_LIBRARIES} )

if( APPLE )
    set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_BITCODE "NO" )
    set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES RESOURCE "${RESOURCES}" )
    #set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE SampleBrowser_OSX.icns)
    set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} \
        -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework Metal  -framework StoreKit" )

    if( APPLE_IOS )
        # iPhone
        set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} \
            -framework UIKit -framework CoreText -framework CoreMotion" )

        # These must be global for all projects; or else they'll cause
        # trouble or increased compiling times
        set( CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.0" )
        set( CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_VALID_ARCHS "arm64" )

        set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Scripts/Apple/iPhone/iOSApp.plist
            # XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS
            #   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Scripts/Apple/iPhone/iOSEntitlements.plist"
        )
    else()
        # macOS
        set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -framework Foundation" )
        set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
            MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Scripts/Apple/macOS/macOSApp.plist
            # XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS
            #   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Scripts/Apple/macOS/macOSEntitlements.plist"
        )
    endif()
endif()
```

Ogre Version: the newest ogre-next version idk
OS: macOS Big Sur

I also don't have a `sdk` folder, I don't have any `OGRE` folders in `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/include`, but I don't know if that's a problem.

I tried hardcoding the paths or something and not using cmake at all, but nothing just seems to work.

Comment: So, what is content of the line referred in the error message (`build.ninja:240`)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev This is the content: `LINK_LIBRARIES = -Wl,-rpath,/Users/fildom/Developer/Ogre/my_ogre_project/Dependencies/Ogre/build/lib/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/$(CONFIGURATION)  -lOgreAtmosphere  -lOgreOverlay  -lOgreHlmsUnlit  -lOgreHlmsPbs  -lOgreMain  /usr/local/lib/libSDL2main.a  /usr/local/lib/libSDL2.dylib  -framework Cocoa`

Comment: Well, that `$(PLATFORM_NAME)` and `$(CONFIGURATION)` seem to be a problem. It is unlikely that CMake generated them for a Ninja generator, so it looks like some CMake script writes them into some variable or property. Probably, this is script `CMake/Bootstrap.cmake`, or `CMake/Dependencies/OGRE.cmake`, or some other script shipped with your project and included by those scripts. Try to search these constructions in your project's files.